# Java User input time

Tags: java, time, localdate

Im working on a To-Do list program.

I want to make it for the user possible to input a date, time and regarding. I already have the date. What Im missing is the time.

```
DateTimeFormatter formateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"); 
LocalDate timeNotFormated = null;
String time = "22:22";   //* here is the user input for example 22:22
timeNotFormated = LocalDate.parse(time, formateTime);
System.out.println(timeNotFormated);
```

But I get many exceptions. Is there something Im missing something?

Exception observed:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text '22:22' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from
> TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 22:22 of type
> java.time.format.Parsed

The exception happens in the following line:

```
timeNotFormated = LocalDate.parse(time, formateTime);
```

Comment: You'd have to paste the exceptions you get, obviously.

Comment: ? Sry Im pretty new in Java, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: You said you get exceptions when running your code. The [Comment by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593525/java-user-input-time/72593592#comment128232703_72593525) asks that you copy-paste the text of the exception messages into the body of your Question. Most of us here reading your Question are not clairvoyant.

Comment: work through a tutorial on using the Date/Time classes..

Comment: The `LocalDate` class is for a date without time of day. For the opposite, a time of day without date, you need a `LocalTime`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

See [*Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) by Oracle.

```
LocalTime.parse( "23:45" )
```

## `LocalTime`

The class [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) represents a time-of-day only, without a date, and without a time zone or offset.

## ISO 8601

Your example string input complies with the ISO 8601 standard format. The *java.time* classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to provide a formatting pattern.

## Example code

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "22:22" ) ;
```

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot. How can I parse the LocalTime to a string back? And can I catch exceptions if the user input something like 25:72

Comment: @PizzaE4ter Time for you to learn how to ***read the documentation***. Asking Stack Overflow to write each line of code for your app will become very tedious for both you and us. I provided a link to the Javadoc. Start by scanning that linked page for methods whose name contains the word “String”. Then read its description to judge if it does what you want.

Comment: @PizzaE4ter As for handling exceptions, ***read the documentation***. The Javadoc lists exceptions thrown by each method. That might be a good place to start.

Comment: @PizzaE4ter Oracle provides at no cost [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) with a [chapter on the *java.time* classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Always study these tutorials before posting here.